# Why does a for loop over a cell array wrap the loop variable in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell-array

Taking the following MWE

```
for q = { {1,2}, {3,4} }
   disp(q{1})        % Displays 1x2 cell array
   disp(q{1}{1})     % Displays first element
end
```

This gives the output

```
[1]    [2]
 1
[3]    [4]
 3
```

In other words, `q` becomes `{{1,2}}` instead of `{1,2}`. I would have expected the latter behaviour.

Is there any rationale for this behaviour? I have a hard time picturing a scenario where you would not want to do `q=q{1}` before working with `q`. Or am I doing something wrong in setting up the loop?

Comment: Interesting... Anything on the documentation regarding iterating over cell arrays?

Comment: Not a dupe. You ask about the rationale, unlike the other question, which explicitly puts that aside

Comment: @LuisMendo You're right! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
for index = valArray
```

Matlab's applies `()` indexing, even if `valArray` is a cell array. As the [documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) says,

> Creates a column vector, `index`, from subsequent columns of array `valArray` on each iteration. For example, on the first iteration, `index = valArray(:,1)`. The loop executes a maximum of `n` times, where `n` is the number of columns of `valArray`, given by `numel(valArray(1,:))`. The input `valArray` can be of any MATLAB data type, including a character vector, cell array, or struct.

As to *why* it behaves like this, I see two reasons. First, to maintain semantics of the `for` loop: it always applies `()` indexing.

Second, consider the case that `ValArray` is a 2D cell array such as

```
valArray = {1,     'aa',    [];
            'hey', {10 20}, 'bbb'};
```

Applying `{}` indexing in the `for` loop would be incompatible with picking a *column* in each iteration. For example, in the first iteration you would get *two* values, namely `1` and `hey`. To ensure that `index` gets *one* value, they need to be kept within a (column) cell array `{1; 'hey'}`, which is what `for` does.

Comment: Right. Curly braces indexing would only make sense if `valArray` was of size `1xN`.